# SSRS Excel Exporting Error

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have Created SSRS Report with 25 Columns and when i run Report it fetch around 15000+ records but when i Export the Report in Excel Format it gives Error on Report Server and Local machine .i.e. "The Communication Object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel, cannot be Used for Communication Because it is in the Faulted State" it takes 3 minutes to execute Query in SQL 2008 R2 (SQL Server i am using) and 5 min to show on Report. What could be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found some problem with my last Column i.e. Comments which contains more text (in some case's it's more than 36000 characters) so it works perfectly without the column Comments but still not sure about the Problem.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

these kind of problems occur most of the time because of limitations of excell itself.
please check the following maximum limits:

Worksheet size - 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns
Column width - 255 characters
Row height - 409 points
Page breaks-1,026 horizontal and vertical
Total number of characters that a cell can contain-32,767 characters
Characters in a header or footer-255
Sheets in a workbook-Limited by available memory (default is 3 sheets)